# A Problem with Hidden Move Go

Tags: go

I have just learned about [Hidden Move Go](https://senseis.xmp.net/?HiddenMoveGo) and I have a problem.

Let us assume that one of our opponent’s hidden stones has only one liberty, i.e. it is in atari. But they don’t know that, because one of our three surrounding stones is hidden. So they play somewhere else and we play a stone filling the last liberty of their hidden stone. In this position we have no idea that we have captured a stone and our opponent has no idea that their stone is captured. Because of this, the table is wrong and it mustn’t be. How can we avoid that situation without the help of a third person? Any ideas or experiences?

Comment: You write “the table is wrong and it mustn’t”: do you mean “the position on the board is incorrect”?

Answer (score 2):

As I read [the description in Sensei’s Library](https://senseis.xmp.net/?HiddenMoveGo) (your own link), hidden moves are not considered to be played on the board until they are revealed; you may like to think of the stone as still in a special pot with a label on it. So a not yet revealed stone cannot be captured or in atari. It can, however, be used to prevent a move your opponent tries to make.

In your example, the hidden stone is therefore **not** in atari: neither it nor your hidden stone are even on the board. You next move does **not** capture the hidden stone. The board (which I suppose you mean by ‘table’) is **not** wrong. **No** third person is required.

Comment: The hidden stones are more like ghosts, then, which "possess" any stone that would be placed there by the opponent.